# Delete object instance from class function in python

Tags: python

I would like to delete an instance of my object after executing a function so that no python script can access this instance anymore.

Here is my code:

```
class MyClass():
    def myFunc(self):
       ...
       del self

myClass = MyClass()
myClass.myFunc()
print(myClass) # Supposed to raise an error because myClass is supposed to be deleted but that's not the case
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: You cannot delete objects in Python, Python is a memory-managed language. `del` *deletes names from namespaces* not objects. You simply deleted the local variable `self`, which ceases to exist after the function executes anyway so it is totally pointless

Comment: All that you will do with the `del` statement is delete the reference in the local variable `self` - which was about to happen anyway when the method returns. Other references to the same object are unaffected.

Comment: You can't actually delete the instance - but you can certainly put it in a state where nothing further can be done with it (similar to how a closed file object still exists, but produces an "operation attempted on closed file" exception for most methods).  This could be done by adding a flag attribute, that all of your methods check before doing anything, or perhaps simply by deleting critical attributes such that any method on the object would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood how `del` works. It does not remove objects. It removes names.

For example, say you have

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = x
>>> z = x
```

All three names, `x`, `y`, `z` refer to the same list object. Now delete `x`:

```
>>> del x
>>> x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

It would make no sense for `y` and `z` to raise a `NameError` after this. Imagine especially if `y` and `z` were references in a different function or module. Having `del x` make other references disappear would lead to some very unexpected and undesirable behaviors.

So under normal circumstances, you can't quite do what you want to do. Your current method is just removing the name `self` in the local namespace of the method itself. It can not easily modify the global namespace.

That being said, you can write a function that removes a name from the global namespace. For example:

```
class MyClass:
    def myFunc(self, name):
        del globals()[name]

myInst = MyClass()
myInst.myFunc('myInst')
```

Now, if you attempt to access `myInst`, the name will be gone in the script. This is a bad idea, and likely won't delete the object at all anyway. If you had another reference to `myInst`, e.g. in a `list`, `dict` or direct assignment to another name, that reference would persist, and so would the object itself.

A much better approach, as suggested in the comments, is to mark the instance as unusable. For example, you can do something like

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.useable = True

    def my_func(self):
        self._check_useable()

        # do your thing...

        self.useable = False

    def other_func(self, *args):
        self._check_useable()
        # Do stuff to args ...

    def _check_useable(self):
        if not self.useable:
            raise ValueError('Class is not useable!')
```

There are more robust ways of implementing the flag to make it less accessible to the casual user, but they basically follow the same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't delete objects in python and only delete the appearance of variables in the namespace. I would recommend just raising an error once the function is called once. Since you want an error to occur after its run.

```
class MyClass():
   def myFunc(self):
      ...
      counter += 1
      del self

counter = 0
# Check if the function has been run once and then raise exception
if counter > 0:
    raise exception("Instance cannot be used")

myClass = MyClass()
myClass.myFunc()
print(myClass)
```

I hope this still does what you anticipate but the `del` function only deletes the appearance of variable in the namespace and not allowing you to reference it anymore (But its not being deleted).